# Is it possible to implement a command in CodenameOne that will display a PDF once a button is pressed without using a URL

Tags: java, codenameone

I am trying to make a program using the CodenameOne plugin that will display various PDF's when buttons are pressed, but I can't find a way to do this without using a specific URL for each PDF. Is there any possible way to accomplish this by placing the PDF files into a package and calling them when needed? I would assume that I need to use an ActionListener but I really don't know what to do. This is what I have tried so far.

```
        b1L1.addActionListener((e)->File file = new File("/path/to/file.pdf");
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(file));
```

Answer (score 1):

Desktop or other AWT related API's are unavailable. Even `java.io.File` doesn't make sense on Codename One due to mobile OS restrictions on file systems that `java.io` wasn't designed to handle see [this](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html) for the long form explanation.

We have a sample that does exactly this taken from [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/open-file-rendering.html):

```
Form hi = new Form("PDF Viewer", BoxLayout.y());
Button devGuide = new Button("Show PDF");
devGuide.addActionListener(e -> {
    FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
    String fileName = fs.getAppHomePath() + "pdf-sample.pdf";
    if(!fs.exists(fileName)) {
        Util.downloadUrlToFile("http://www.polyu.edu.hk/iaee/files/pdf-sample.pdf", fileName, true);
    }
    Display.getInstance().execute(fileName);
});
hi.add(devGuide);

hi.show();
```

Comment: The code was helpful so thank you for that. But when I create links for my PDF files and try to open it while the program is running it says that the file type is not supported. I am using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC to create the links. Should I be using something else?

Comment: I haven't used that tool so I have no idea. Does that tool generate a downloadable HTTPS URL?

Comment: Yes it does. What tool do you use?

Comment: I just use a webserver or dropbox